# Electronic ticket with no printer

Tags: tickets, airlines, united-airlines

How can I fly if I can't print my electronic ticket at home to take to the airport?  My printer is giving out very faded copies.

Comment: You can ask the airline to print the ticket for you. Or you can save the ticket to a mobile device and have that scanned by the airline when checking-in.

Comment: What airline and from what airport does the flight depart?

Comment: You can't print an electronic ticket; at best you can print a summary of the data it contains, for information purposes only. Did you mean *boarding pass*?

Comment: You don't need to actually print your eticket and bring it to the airport. It is enough to bring your passport and go to the check-in counter. Since the ticker is virtual - they have your reservation (based on your passport number, typically) in their computer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Out of curiosity, wouldn't a traditional paper ticket also require them to have the reservation in their system before they honor it? Or is the difference that they somehow have to honor it even if they don't see it in their systems? Because otherwise I never really understood the difference between the two...

Comment: Couldn't you get to another printer at an internet cafe or something? It is United Airlines we are talking about, better be safe than sorry. You don't want to be thrown out with your blood all over your faded printout.

Comment: @Mehrdad The ticket (whether an eticket or a paper ticket) is a financial document; the airline has to handle it in accordance with appropriate auditing procedures. Reservations simply hold space for someone; they can be made at will. It is quite possible to have one without the other. If you have "open" sectors on your ticket (whether an eticket or a paper ticket) then you can show up at the airport, and if space is available on the desired flights in the appropriate booking class, reservations will be made immediately for you. [Assuming you can find someone who still knows how to do this.]

Comment: @Mehrdad In the end the (e)ticket wins, so if your reservations somehow got removed or deleted from the system then the airline will have to do what it can to reroute you to your destination. This can and does happen, especially when several airlines are involved in the itinerary, or the itinerary was manually ticketed. That is one reason why regular travellers love apps that watch their reservations for them.

Comment: @Calchas: Thanks but that still leaves me wondering what the difference between the two is haha. Like why do you need to bring your paper ticket but not your eticket when both of them are equivalent to the airline?

Comment: @Mehrdad Your eticket is retained on a computer server by the airline (or the issuing airline if several airlines are involved).  You cannot bring it with you because you never have it. You can print a boarding pass or a receipt but none of these are actually a ticket. They are just pieces of paper that allow the airline to find your ticket more quickly.

Comment: @Calchas: I mean, yes, I understand *that* much, but that's like me asking you what the difference is between water and Coca-Cola, and you telling me the the difference is that one is brown/black and the other is clear/blue. Yes, I can see that myself... that totally misses the point of the question. The point is, why in the world are there two choices when there can be just one. Clearly both of them must have some advantages?

Answer (score 10):

With most airlines, you can print your boarding pass for free at the airport, either from an automatic check in terminal, or at a check in desk, or at a bag drop desk. A small number of budget airlines charge for printing boarding passes at the airport, but United Airlines is not one of them.

Alternatively, United Airlines provides an app that enables you to use your smartphone to display the boarding pass. This is usually the most convenient method in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

1: Just print out a poor copy at home, take it to the airport, show it to the check in agent and the agent will replace it with one their machines can scan.

2: Check in online, go to the computer kiosk at the airport, print out new boarding passes.

3: Check in online, ask the baggage check person to print boarding passes because your printer at home is not working.

4: Get the app, but it may not work everywhere, especially at small or foreign airports where United has but one or two flights and shares gates with multiple airlines.

Answer (score 2):

I've not printed my ticket for years.  I either have it on my phone, or I just hand over my ID at the checkin counter and tell them the flight I'm on. Zero issues.

In the past two months I've done this for flights from Sydney, Melbourne, Tauranga, Christchurch, Auckland, Bangkok, and Krabi, and they didn't flinch - just looked me/us up and printed out the boarding pass.

If you're concerned, take the faded version to the airport with you as a backup, and if the ticket machines / kiosks exist for your airline, re-print, or go up to the counter and ask for them to re-print.  Also check if you can check-in on line first, as it might make the process a little faster.